# Is with Editra 0.7.08 a reliable IDE?

Tags: python, ide

I have been using this particular IDE (Editra) for about a year, previously it was version 0.6.77, the latest is version 0.7.08, after updating to the the newer version I built the exe with py2exe. The ide works fine, but Norton's Avirus flagged and quarantined it. The primary reason I use it is because it can be configured to run on different versions of Python from a single drop down box, so I have it set use Python 2.6 and/or Python 3.1. Does anyone else use Editra? and if so, does it trigger your Anti-virus? or should I stick with IDLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Editra in a while, but I think it's just the py2exe binary that's flagged the antivirus (which is subject to false positives). You can run the Editra source (IIRC, Editra comes with wxPython) directly. As per Editra vs IDLE, I'm sure Editra has some more functionality than IDLE.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: ,Thanks. I tried using py2exe on another py file and Norton 360 triggered an alert on that exe also, I guess for now I should just stick with running the pyw file to use Editra.